# Sending Data via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, transmission

I'm a little confused about how to send data over a Bluetooth connection.  In the Android API documentation, from the Bluetooth Chat example, the **class BluetoothChat.java** constructs a Handler object.  Within there is a switch statement, and a `MESSAGE_WRITE` case.  Do I need to implement similar code to send Strings over Bluetooth?  A case statement for each String I want to send? In particular I want to **send `(name,value)` pairs** so I know what is sent and what it's value is.  How do I implement this?  If, following the example, I call `BluetoothChatService.write(String.getBytes())` a bunch of times to send...?  Then how would I know which strings are associated with which names?  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to send structured data over bluetooth connections in my Android app.  protobuf takes care of figuring out how to serialize the message for you so that you only have to send a byte value (length of the message) and then the serialized message; the library takes care of unserializing the message on the other end and populating the fields of a custom object.  Definitely take a look at it; it made the writing of a custom bluetooth socket protocol quite easy.

Comment: Have you found the need to break the messages into smaller "chunks" to support the minimum BLE message length of 23?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize pairs to any of formats which allows byte representation. Such as XML or JSON. Or even your custom format, it wouldn't be difficult for pairs of strings. And then send it.

Comment: So something like this:  

MyObject implements Serializable
{
 String name;
 String value; 

 MyObject(String name, String value)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.value=value;
 }
 
 String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }
 
 String getVal()
 {
  return value;
 }

}


and then in the bluetooth code:

MyObject pair = new MyObject("a","b");

OutputStream.write(pair.getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

For simple pairs of strings (Such as names), you could simply use some character to define when the first string stops, and the next begins.

For example, I use a format such as this to send a set of 3 strings from one device to another:

```
String toSend = partOne + ":" + partTwo + ":" + partThree;
```

On the other device, to get the strings you sent, use the String.split() method like so:

```
String parts[] = received.split(":",3);
```

The 2nd parameter is a limit to how many times to split. In this example, there are 3 strings, so split 3 times max.

The downside to doing this is that you need to use characters that will *never* be in all but the last string.

In my application, I used this method to send data about text messages, and the first 2 parts are the phone number and timestamp, so there can never be a : in it. For names, a newline would probably work.

If your going to send more complex data, definitely use something like Protocol Buffers.

Comment: Looking back on this, what I meant was to serialize the data. I wrote this when I was young, before I had ever known about serialization. Today I would recommend using JSON