# Transfer constructed data via android Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, gesture, android-bluetooth

I have a data structure representing gestures event:

```
public class GestureData {

    private int gestureType;
    private float arg1;
    private float arg2;

    public GestureData (int gestureType, float arg1, float arg2) {
        this.gestureType = gestureType;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to transfer this object via bluetooth, from the android to the pc.
I have found the [current post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609373/sending-data-via-bluetooth/6614476#6614476) suggesting [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).
Is this a good practice for this purpose?